# Levantar archivos de propiedades en el Tomcat segun el ambiente

Tags: java, tomcat

Tengo un war que lo levanto con tomcat 8, necesito cargar un archivo de propiedades segun en el ambiente en el que estoy (dev, test o prod) que estan en la carpeta "conf" del tomcat.
¿Que me recomiendan utilizar?

Answer (score 0):

Según el ambiente supongo tienes una base de datos para cada uno. Puedes hacer una tabla de propierties que tenga esa información y obtenerla mediante una clase encargada netamente para eso, así, cuando cambies de base de datos, las propierties serán según el ambiente de esa bd.

Comment: Para realizar la consulta a la tabla de properties ya tengo que tener las credenciales para acceder a la base y ahi obtengo los datos para conectarme posiblemente a otra base, la idea es conectarme a la primera vez a la base que voy a utilizar. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Por eso te recomendaría hacer un pull de conexiones, aunque con tomcat...